# How to render fullCalendar using AJAX

Tags: ajax, fullcalendar

I want to render a calendar with fullCalendar **using AJAX**. I'm trying it right now but I'm not getting it to work.

**EDIT**

In the client side I have:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".goto", function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault(); 

   var rel = $(this).attr('rel'); 

   $.post('./controller.php',{ page: rel },function(data) {
       $('#ajaxlayer').html(data); 
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render'); 
    }); 
});
```

And the PHP returns:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Well show us some code and how are you doing that. What are you using server side, and the code on how are you making the AJAX call.

Comment: In the client side I have:

`$( document ).on( "click", ".goto", function(e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
  
  $.post('./controller.php',{ page: rel },function(data) {

    
        $('#ajaxlayer').html(data);
    
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
   
  });
   
   
 });`

And the PHP returns: 
`<div id='calendar'></div>`

Comment: Have you tried doing a complete HTML page with all tags and includes including fullcalendar.js and all the stuff needed server side? and instead of just sending in the calendar div send the whole thing, and in cliente side do an iframe?

Comment: Another thing try and use instead of $.post -> $.ajax...

Comment: The thing is, I can't render the fullcalendar in the PHP file, I can only output the empty div (named calendar). Later, in the JS section, with the `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render'); ` instruction, it should render the calendar in the div, but it's not working.

I have also checked with $ajax but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I changed the JS callback as follows:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".goto", function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault(); 

   var rel = $(this).attr('rel'); 

   $.post('./controller.php',{ page: rel },function(data) {
       $('#ajaxlayer').html(data); 
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         header: {
           left: 'prev,next today',
           center: 'title',
           right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
         },
         editable: true,
         events: 'eventos.json');
       }); 
  });
```